# How do I convert this a href into a Rails friendly link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to convert this:

```
<a class="btn btn-google-plus" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=SHAREMESSAGE" title="Share on Google+" target="_blank">
     <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
</a>
```

Into a Rails friendly `link_to` that not uses `post.title` in the URL and also includes a link to the current post.

In other words, I started by doing this in HTML like this:

```
<a class="btn btn-google-plus" href='https://plus.google.com/share?url=<%= "#{post.title} - Read more at #{post}" %>' title="Share on Google+" target="_blank">
    <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
</a>
```

The issue with this is that this generates a URL like this (the Twitter equivalent, but the principle is the same):

`http://twitter.com/home?status=PNPYO%20saddened%20at%20passing%20of%20Roger%20Clarke%20-%20Read%20more%20at%20#<Post:0x00000101660e98>`

Where it returns a `Post` object. The issue I ran into quickly, was that I wasn't quite sure how to generate a `link_to` within a `link_to`. Is that even possible?

This is how I want the final status on Twitter to look:

```
PNPYO saddened at passing of Roger Clarke - Read More at http://example.com/pnpyo-saddened-at-passing-of-roger-clarke
```

How do I achieve this in the most Rails-friendly way possible? I am not averse to just using regular a href tags, if it can't be done with a `link_to` helper. But either way, I still need to be able to generate a `link_to` within the status message.

Comment: Why you’d need link_to for this?

Comment: issue is at `Read more at #{post}` change it to: `#{link_to 'Read more at', post_url(post)}` since just `post` will not return the absolute path.

Comment: @Smar Why not use a `link_to` when I can? Or is it faster to just go straight `a href`?

Comment: @Surya I tested that...and it came out as an `<a href="https://someurl.com"></a>` URL on Twitter - rather than an actual link. Thoughts?

Comment: at the place of `post_url(post)` should be URL you're expecting, I am not sure what you're exactly expecting there so you might have to check it out yourself. it can't be some random someurl.com for sure.

Comment: @marcamillion: It needs to generate the link, so of course hardcoding the link is better. But more importantly, since all of this is custom information, even though you should be able to generate a link like that, it will require just hardcoding the values to the link_to, so it doesn’t give you any dynamic benefits that are point of the link_to (to start with, the url generation...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to call a `link_to` within a `link_to`, but you want to call an *url_helper* directly.

`link_to` in rails is a helper method which generates the necessary html code for links. Whether you want to use this convenience function or not, what you are searching for is a direct method to generate an *url* that you can concatenate into a string.

Simply use the following as the href for your anchor:

```
http://twitter.com/home?status=<%=u "#{post.title} - Read more at #{post_url(post)}" %>
```

(<%=u %> performs the url encoding of the string)

Comment: I updated your answer, because the `<%u` doesn't print to screen - so I was getting a blank status message. In the current form, it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Ah sorry. Glad it helped anyway!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve as follow :

```
<%= link_to "https://plus.google.com/share?url=#{post.title} - Read more at #{post}", :class => "btn btn-google-plus" :title => "Share on Google+" :target => "_blank" do %>
  <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I am going to go with the static URL from Peter's answer, but you actually did provide me with the info I wanted. Thanks!